# Lotus notes in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, lotus-notes

Is there anything exists Notes connector for **Outlook 2007** or any other way to use Notes on **Outlook 2007** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Lotus Notes Administrators consider [DAMO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/damo/)  DAMO is "Domino Access for Microsoft Outlook" and would allow seamless synchronisation between Outlook clients and a Domino Server.  Your admins would have to [do a few things](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/damo/#N10070) and you would have to install the DAMO client on top of your Outlook.

The bad news is that in June, IBM announced they were not planning to continue upgrade DAMO.  The current version is based on the 8.0 Domino and getting older by the day.

There are some [posts](http://lntoiphone.blogspot.com/2009/06/lotus-domin-to-outlook-2007-answer.html) out there that indicate using DAMO and Outlook 2007 together may require a bit of playing around to get them right.  I used DAMO for several years on Windows XP (Outlook 2002 / 2003) and Lotus Notes 6.x and never had any problems with it.